# on mouse over change image on html

Tags: javascript, html, image, mouseover

I was trying to make an image to change on mouse over. This piece of code works for IE but not for the other browsers like chrome, opera, safari, etc. Any ideas?

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.myimage1.src='img/login_button_22.jpg';"
onmouseout="document.myimage1.src='img/login_button_11.jpg';">    
<img src="img/login_button_11.jpg" name="myimage1" /> </a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using a ID, not a NAME, and using `document.getElementById` to select the element.

IMG elements, not being FORM elements, should not be able to take on a NAME property, but Microsoft managed to screw this up.

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myimage1').src='img/login_button_22.jpg';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('myimage1').src='img/login_button_11.jpg';">    
<img src="img/login_button_11.jpg" id="myimage1" /></a>
```

Also, it's much easier and cleaner to use a CSS background and a `:hover` declaration and skip doing this using JavaScript completely.

**Here's how:**

HTML:

```
<a class="mybutton" href="#"></a>
```

CSS (adjust dimensions accordingly):

```
.myButton {
     width:100px;
     height:50px;
     display:block;
     background-image:url(../img/login_button_11.jpg);

}

.myButton:hover {
     background-image:url(../img/login_button_22.jpg)
}
```

Comment: trying it I can tell that it still works perfect on IE but again not working in all other explorers...

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="" onMouseOver="document.MyImage.src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/round-edge-social/72/ask-icon.png';" onMouseOut="document.MyImage.src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/round-edge-social/72/arto-icon.png';">
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/round-edge-social/72/arto-icon.png" name="MyImage">
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/W6zs5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src='img/login_button_11.jpg' onmouseover="this.src='img/login_button_22.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='img/login_button_11.jpg';" />
```