# change image on hover for each image in a gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a page full of images something like this, more or less:

```
<div class="category">
<ul class="grid">                         
    <li class="item first">
        <a href="/pic1.html" title="PIC1" class="image"><span><img src="/pic1-1.jpg" data-hover="/pic1-2.jpg" width="243" height="243" /></span></a>
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="/pic1.html" title="PIC1-1">PIC1</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="/pic2.html" title="PIC2" class="image"><span><img src="/pic1.jpg" width="243" height="243" /></span></a>
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="/pic2.html" title="PIC2-1">PIC2</a></h2>
    </li>


    <li class="item last">
        <a href="/pic3.html" title="PIC3" class="image"><span><img src="/pic3-1.jpg" data-hover="/pic3-2.jpg"width="243" height="243" /></span></a>
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="/pic3.html" title="PIC3-1">PIC3</a></h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

For each item in the list, I'd like to have a second image that only shows on mouse hover if another image has been provided for that list item in the html.

How might I do this in the html and the corresponding javascript?

Comment: where is the second image? can you share a markup with 2 images

Comment: Can you explain this *if another image has been provided for that list item in the html*

Comment: Hadn't gotten that far. But I changed it to reflect part of Milind's answer. Changed the markup. So the first and third items in the list have a alternative jpg that the image should change to on mouse over. The second does not have a alternative jpg in the markup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587391/on-mouse-over-change-image-on-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(function () {
$('img').each(function () {
    $(this).data('original', this.src)
}).mouseenter(function () {
    $(this)
        .attr('src', $(this).data('hover'))
        .animate({
        marginTop: 0,
        marginRight: 0,
        marginLeft: 0,
        borderWidth: 10
    }, 'fast')
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this)
        .attr('src', $(this).data('original'))
    .animate({
        marginTop: 20,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
        borderWidth: 0
    }, 'fast')
})
})
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/9qGtv/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

With javascript arrays you can make like this

```
<script>
var a=0;
function show_next()
{
var imgg = new Array();
imgg[0] = "pic1.jpg";
imgg[1] = "pic2.jpg";
imgg[2] = "pic3.jpg";
if (a>imgg.length-1)
{
a=0;
}
document.getElementById("image").src=imgg[a];
document.getElementById("show").title=imgg[a];
document.getElementById("show").href=imgg[a];
document.getElementById("show_2").href=imgg[a];
document.getElementById("name_image").innerHTML=imgg[a];
a=a+1;
}
</script>

<div class="category">
<ul class="grid">                         
<li class="item first">
<a href="/pic1.html" title="PIC1" class="image" onmouseover="show_next();" id="show"><span><img src="" width="243" height="243" id="image" / ></span></a>
<h2 class="product-name" ><a href="/pic1.html" title="PIC1-1"  id="show_2"><span id="name_image">PIC1</span></a></h2>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".image").on('hover', function(event) {
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).next().data('src'));
}
```

The code above will execute each time you hover one of the images of the page and then fetchs the data attribute form the next element of that `image`:

```
<image class="image" src="yourock.jpg">
<span style="display:none" data-src="yousuck.jpg"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain javascript it would be something like:
In head section add this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function swapimg(img)
     {
         /* If second image is not provided stop execution */
         if(img.getAttribute('data-hover') == '') return;

         var currentSRC = img.src;
         img.src = img.getAttribute('data-hover');
         img.setAttribute('data-hover', currentSRC);
     }
</script>
```

Then in your code add onmouseover and onmouseout

```
<div class="category">
<ul class="grid">                         
<li class="item first">
    <a href="/pic1.html" title="PIC1" class="image"><span><img src="/pic1-1.jpg" data-hover="/pic1-2.jpg" onmouseover="swapimg(this);" onmouseout="swapimg(this);" width="243" height="243" /></span></a>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="/pic1.html" title="PIC1-1">PIC1</a></h2>
</li>
<li class="item">
    <a href="/pic2.html" title="PIC2" class="image"><span><img src="/pic1.jpg" width="243" height="243" onmouseover="swapimg(this);" onmouseout="swapimg(this);" /></span></a>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="/pic2.html" title="PIC2-1">PIC2</a></h2>
</li>


<li class="item last">
    <a href="/pic3.html" title="PIC3" class="image"><span><img src="/pic3-1.jpg" data-hover="/pic3-2.jpg"width="243" height="243" onmouseover="swapimg(this);" onmouseout="swapimg(this);" /></span></a>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="/pic3.html" title="PIC3-1">PIC3</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```